# How to trigger animations when scrolled to particular section of the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, scroll

**what i have achieved=>** I have a single pager website with parallax scroll effect.
 animations triggered on page load.

**what i want to achieve=>** when user clicks on menu on top it scroll down to that div section and particular animation assigned with the div need to be played. Currently animation are playing On page load.

Is any solution to this? Is it achieved with identifying scroll position?

your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please post your code HTML/CSS/JS

Answer (score 1):

please try this code

```
var YoudivOffst = $('#element').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var windScllTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( YoudivOffst  > windScllTop    ){
      //your function here
    }else{
      //your else function here
    }

});
```